# Problem with merging two lidars

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, 2dlidar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

Can someone explain why this is happening? I am using the [ira_laser_tools.](https://github.com/iralabdisco/ira_laser_tools) [image: image description]

**NOTE:** The L corresponds to the right as you see the robot in the picture and R to the left.

```
<gazebo reference="sick_L_laser">
<material value="Gazebo/Blue" />
<sensor type="ray" name="sick_lms_5_laser_gazebo_v0">
  <always_on>true</always_on>
  <update_rate>100.0</update_rate>
  <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
  <visualize>false</visualize>
  <ray>
    <scan>
      <horizontal>
        <samples>720</samples>
        <resolution>1</resolution>
        <min_angle>-1.5708</min_angle> <!--90 moires -->
        <max_angle>2.44346</max_angle> <!--140 moires -->
      </horizontal>
    </scan>
    <range>
      <min>0.05</min>
      <max>10.0</max>
      <resolution>0.01</resolution>
    </range>
  </ray>
  <plugin name="gazebo_ros_sick_lms_5_laser_gazebo_v0_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_laser.so">
    <gaussianNoise>0.0005</gaussianNoise>
    <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
    <updateRate>100.0</updateRate>
    <topicName>scan_L</topicName>     
    <frameName>sick_L_laser</frameName>
  </plugin>
</sensor>
```

```
<gazebo reference="sick_R_laser">
<material value="Gazebo/Blue" />
<sensor type="ray" name="sick_lms_5_laser_gazebo_v0">
  <always_on>true</always_on>
  <update_rate>100.0</update_rate>
  <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
  <visualize>true</visualize>
  <ray>
    <scan>
      <horizontal>
        <samples>720</samples>
        <resolution>1</resolution>
        <min_angle>-2.44346</min_angle> <!--140 moires -->
        <max_angle>1.5708</max_angle> <!--90 moires -->
      </horizontal>
    </scan>
    <range>
      <min>0.05</min>
      <max>10.0</max>
      <resolution>0.01</resolution>
    </range>
  </ray>
  <plugin name="gazebo_ros_sick_lms_5_laser_gazebo_v0_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_laser.so">
    <gaussianNoise>0.0005</gaussianNoise>
    <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
    <updateRate>100.0</updateRate>
    <topicName>scan_R</topicName> 
    <frameName>sick_R_laser</frameName>
  </plugin>
</sensor>
```

-- IRA_LASER_TOOLS --

```
    <node pkg="ira_laser_tools" name="laserscan_multi_merger" type="laserscan_multi_merger" output="screen">
        <param name="destination_frame" value="base_link"/>
    <param name="cloud_destination_topic" value="merged_cloud"/>
    <param name="scan_destination_topic" value="scan_multi"/>
            <param name="laserscan_topics" value ="/scan_L /scan_R" /> 

            <param name="angle_min" value="-3.1415"/>
            <param name="angle_max" value="3.1415"/>
            <param name="angle_increment" value="0.0058"/>
            <param name="scan_time" value="0.0333333"/>
            <param name="range_min" value="0.05"/>
            <param name="range_max" value="50.0"/>

</node>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364524/problem-with-merging-two-lidars/) by [al_ca](https://answers.ros.org/users/55624/al_ca/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2020-11-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [harshal](https://answers.ros.org/users/32094/harshal/) on 2020-11-02**:
could you also please upload your config file for ira_laser_tools?

**Comment by [al_ca](https://answers.ros.org/users/55624/al_ca/) on 2020-11-02**:
of course,

**Comment by [harshal](https://answers.ros.org/users/32094/harshal/) on 2020-11-02**:
And have you tested whether the angle min and max are not causing that problem? You in effect have min of -140 and max of 140, instead of +/- 180. Basically, have you already tried adapting all of these params to your laser scanners?

**Comment by [al_ca](https://answers.ros.org/users/55624/al_ca/) on 2020-11-02**:
I have the same angle min and max in the real lidars and no problem appears at all, only in gazebo. So I am wondering I am doing something wrong with gazebo plugins or gazebo has the problem?

**Comment by [harshal](https://answers.ros.org/users/32094/harshal/) on 2020-11-03**:
The Gazebo plugins are supposed to be a model of the real sensor, but do not recreate/represent data in the exact same way. However, if the individual sensors in Gazebo are working properly (without ira_laser_tools), then the problem doesn't seem to be due to Gazebo as the laser_tools package is basically post processing the data and shouldn't affect the plugins themselves.

I would still suggest adapting the ira_laser_tools config for your actual sensors. If it already works fine, then with the correct config, it should work fine too. Then you have a better base of narrowing down the problem. Of course, if by changing the config something stops working as it is now, you can always revert back the config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally, the solution is to put different names to the  <<<name="sick_lms_5_laser_gazebo_v0">>>

For example

and

---

Originally posted by [al_ca](https://answers.ros.org/users/55624/al_ca/) with karma: 79 on 2020-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0